# how to make an image fit perfectly in an iframe without having to scroll

Tags: html

How to make an image fit perfectly in an iframe without having to scroll.
below is an example of my code

```
<iframe  style="display:inline"src="../assessm2/images/social3.jpg"    frameborder="0" name="frame 2"></iframe>
</center><br/>
</div>
<div id="text">
<a href="../assessm2/registration.html" target="frame 1"  >Show</a>
<a href ="../assessm2/images/social2.jpg" target="frame 1">Hide</a> &nbsp 
<a href="../assessm2/shoutOut.html" target="frame 2">Show</a>
<a href="../assessm2/images/social3.jpg" target="frame 2">Hide</a></p></div>
```

Comment: How is this question related to notepad++?

Comment: notepad++ is a text editor, it is not relevant to the question

Comment: Okay so any help with my question?